# OpenStack .NET API , meta data not getting added when passed in with cloudFilesProvider.CreateObjectFromFile

Tags: .net, openstack, rackspace-cloud, rackspace

Unable to add metadata while creating object with cloudFilesProvider.CreateObjectFromFile. Is that supported by cloudFilesProvider.CreateObjectFromFile? Currently i'm doing:

```
DicMetaData.Add("StoreID", inStrContainerID);
DicMetaData.Add("FileType", instrFileType);
DicMetaData.Add("DateCreated", dTDateCreated.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.FFF"));
DicMetaData.Add("isProcessed", "0");
DicMetaData.Add("DateProcessed", DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.FFF"));

cloudFilesProvider.CreateObjectFromFile(inStrContainerID, inStrSrcFilePath, strDesFileName, 4096, DicMetaData);
```

So while calling cloudFilesProvider.CreateObjectFromFile i stepped in all they way to

```
RestService.Stream(absoluteUri, method, stream, chunkSize, maxReadLength, headers, queryStringParameter, requestSettings, progressUpdated);
```

in StreamRESTRequest method of ProviderBase.cs and here the headers count was 6 [5 items i added + X-Auth-Token that gets added before RestService.Stream]

so i know all the items are getting passed to the resquest, but after the object is created, if i do a get cloudFilesProvider.GetObjectMetaData then i get a Dictionary back with count 0.

Then i did

```
cloudFilesProvider.CreateObjectFromFile(inStrContainerID, inStrSrcFilePath, strDesFileName);
cloudFilesProvider.UpdateObjectMetadata(inStrContainerID, strDesFileName, DicMetaData);
```

here if i do a get cloudFilesProvider.GetObjectMetaData i get the added metadata back in the Dictionary.

So how can this be done better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're calling the method with an unexpected argument. The `CreateObjectFromFile` method takes a `headers` dictionary, which is actually the raw HTTP headers to add to the request. Since the `Metadata` class is derived from `Dictionary<string, string>`, your code still compiles when you pass a `Metadata` for this argument, yet the result is not as you'd expect.

There is no direct support in the SDK for including a `Metadata` object in the call to `CreateObjectFromFile`. In addition, the [OpenStack Object Storage API Reference](http://docs.openstack.org/api/openstack-object-storage/1.0/content/) does not include any information about including headers in the underlying [Create Object](http://docs.openstack.org/api/openstack-object-storage/1.0/content/create-update-object.html) API method.

You have two ways you can approach this problem:

1. Use the documented `UpdateObjectMetadata` call after you create the object.
2. Attempt to use an undocumented feature of adding `X-Object-Meta-xxx` metadata in the `headers` passed to the `CreateObjectFromFile` method (this may or may not work, may vary between OpenStack implementations, and may change behavior at any time).

Obviously I recommend you stick with the documented method. :)

Answer (score 0):

So for those curious, i did experiment with option 2 from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18087210/1241496) anwser :

```
DicMetaData.Add("X-Object-Meta-StoreID", inStrContainerID);
DicMetaData.Add("X-Object-Meta-FileType", instrFileType);
DicMetaData.Add("X-Object-Meta-DateFileCreated", dTDateCreated.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.FFF"));
DicMetaData.Add("X-Object-Meta-isProcessed", "0");
DicMetaData.Add("X-Object-Meta-DateProcessed", DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.FFF"));

cloudFilesProvider.CreateObjectFromFile(inStrContainerID, inStrSrcFilePath, strDesFileName, 4096, DicMetaData);

Metadata = cloudFilesProvider.GetObjectMetaData(inStrContainerID, inStrFileName);
```

and ended up raising more issues.

The meta tags did get added to the files but the tag names got changes a little bit.
for entry `X-Object-Meta-isProcessed` i expected a tag called **isProcessed** and when i did a `cloudFilesProvider.GetObjectMetaData` the tag name was **Isprocessed**

Comment: Header keys are required by the HTTP 1.1 specification to be treated as case-insensitive. You should never rely on a particular case for the keys, and your comparisons should always be done using `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`. Also note that this rule applies to services that pass metadata in headers (e.g. Object Storage Service), but not to services that pass them in JSON request/response bodies (e.g. Compute Service for server and image metadata).